# my code for data markup and annotation is not functioning as I expect

Tags: data-annotations

I encountered a problem while creating a data markup and annotation project and I sincerely request help in resolving it. Problem: My task is to label a large amount of data, including images and text, to train a machine learning model. I wrote a Python script to automate this process. However, I encountered several serious difficulties: 1. Execution speed: My code is slow, especially when processing large images. This slows down the entire markup process and makes it inefficient. 2. A bug in the layout algorithm: My layout model sometimes makes mistakes and I can't figure out what exactly the problem is. The labeled data must be of high quality, otherwise training the model will be useless. I would be very grateful for any advice.

I turned to the documentation and developer community forums to find a solution to improve the performance of the code and fix bugs in the algorithm. I also profiled the code using various tools to identify and optimize bottlenecks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you edit your question and include the code? It's hard to say why it may be inefficient without being able to see it.